# How to merge two jsonb objects in Postgres?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have function where I select common fields for task, I have task_type and I need to select different fields by task_type and then return Json. I don't know SQL and Postgres tricks. Please give me hint! thanks

This is my Idea:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION crm.task_select(_task_uid bigint)
    RETURNS jsonb
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    _data jsonb;
    _task jsonb;
    begin
        SELECT
            task.task_uid AS "id",
            task.action_date,
            task.descrtiption,
            sub.subject_data,
            
            dtask.task_type,
            dtask.name AS "task_name",
            dtask.label AS "task_label",
            lbadmin.user_name_reverse(crea) AS "created_by",
            lbadmin.user_name_reverse(upda) AS "updated_by",
            task.created,
            task.updated,
            
            case when dtask.task_type == 'email'
                _task = select crm.selectEmail(task_uid);
            end;

            FROM crm.tasks "task"
            LEFT JOIN abook2.subjects "sub" ON (task.subject_uid = sub.subject_uid)
            LEFT JOIN crm.def_tasks "dtask" ON (task.def_task_uid = dtask.def_task_uid)
            LEFT JOIN lbadmin.users_user "crea" ON (task.insert_user_uid = crea.role_uid)
            LEFT JOIN lbadmin.users_user "upda" ON (task.update_user_uid = upda.role_uid)
            LEFT JOIN crm.emails "email" ON (task.email_uid = email.email_uid)
            WHERE
            (task.task_uid = _task_uid)
            AND (task.org_uid IS NULL)
            AND (task.card_uid IS NULL) into _data;
        
            _data = _task + _data;
    
        
            return _data;   
    END;
$function$
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results. It is unclear what the purpose of this query is.

Comment: I just need the construction, how to do this, i mean that i have base select and on dtask.task_type I will have cause then statetmen what will add data depend on task_type and i need to merge it

Answer (score 1):

````
Solution that helped me to get array of json objects:
select to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)))
               from (select typ,prop from bgb where id=b.id) t )```
````